# Programatic UIViews being rotated correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, orientation, device-orientation

I have been doing pretty much all of my User Interface programmatically with slight alterations being performed in Interface Builder.. but 99% of all the UI is exclusively done in code, because I feel there is a certain amount of flexibility gained by doing it this way.

However I am now having issues dealing with the rotation of the device, as I have several UIViews being added as subviews I am faced with a rotational problem as this is how I declare the views generally

```
htmlTest.webViewTest.frame = CGRectMake(4.0, 4.0, 312.0, 363.0);
```

and because of this fixed CGRectMake when the device is rotated the view stays the same size and dosent fit the orientation of the view properly.

So I have worked on a solution which is in my opinion horrible.. There are a couple of views that I animate in and users can select options from them then I animate them out.. but they need to be able to handle loading in either portrait or landscape and then if while they are loaded they need to be able to handle a rotation from either orientation to the other.

This is how I have done one of the views.

```
#pragma createAwesomeJumpBar
- (void)jumpBarButtonPosition:(int)changeView
{
    // ChangeView is used to check if the this method is being called from a device rotation or from a button press (0, being rotation and 1, being tabbarButton touch

    // if tabbar selected
    if (changeView == 1) {
        if  ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            if (![jumpBarContainerPortrait superview]) {
                // load portrait view
                jumpBarContainerPortrait = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 480.0, 320, (jumpBarHeightPortrait + 49.0))];
                jumpBarContainerPortrait.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

                // add jumpbar container to view
                [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerPortrait belowSubview:actionTabBar];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                                      delay:0.0f
                                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                                 animations:^{

                                     jumpBarContainerPortrait.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, (367 - jumpBarHeightPortrait), 320.0, (jumpBarHeightPortrait + 49.0)); // display jumpBar


                                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     if (finished) {
                                         NSLog(@"YAY!");
                                     }
                                 }];
            }
            else if ([jumpBarContainerPortrait superview]) {
                //unload portrait view
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                                      delay:0.0f
                                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                                 animations:^{

                                     jumpBarContainerPortrait.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 480.0, 320.0, (jumpBarHeightPortrait + 49.0)); // display jumpBar

                                     // remove selected tabButton highlight
                                     [actionTabBar setSelectedItem:nil];


                                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     if (finished) {

                                         // remove subView for superView
                                         [jumpBarContainerPortrait removeFromSuperview];

                                     }
                                 }];

            }

        }
        else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            if (![jumpBarContainerLandscape superview]) {
                // load landscape view
                jumpBarContainerLandscape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 320, 480.0, (jumpBarHeightLandscape + 49.0))];
                jumpBarContainerLandscape.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

                // add jumpbar container to view
                [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerLandscape belowSubview:actionTabBar];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                                      delay:0.0f
                                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                                 animations:^{

                                     jumpBarContainerLandscape.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, (207 - jumpBarHeightLandscape), 480.0,  (jumpBarHeightLandscape + 49.0)); // display jumpBar


                                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     if (finished) {
                                         NSLog(@"YAY!");
                                     }
                                 }];
            }
            else if ([jumpBarContainerLandscape superview]) {
                // remove landscape view
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                                      delay:0.0f
                                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                                 animations:^{

                                     jumpBarContainerLandscape.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 320, 480.0, (jumpBarHeightLandscape + 49.0)); // display jumpBar

                                     [actionTabBar setSelectedItem:nil];

                                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     if (finished) {

                                         // remove subView for superView
                                         [jumpBarContainerLandscape removeFromSuperview];
                                     }
                                 }];
            }

        }
    }
    // if device rotated selected
    else if (changeView == 0) {
        if  ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            if([jumpBarContainerLandscape superview])
            {
            // Device is changing from landscape to protrait change views to fit
            // load landscape view
            jumpBarContainerPortrait = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, (367 - jumpBarHeightPortrait), 320.0, (jumpBarHeightPortrait + 49.0))];
            jumpBarContainerPortrait.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
            jumpBarContainerPortrait.alpha = 1.0;

            // add jumpbar container to view

                [UIView transitionFromView:jumpBarContainerLandscape
                                    toView:jumpBarContainerPortrait
                                  duration:animationSpeed
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                                completion:NULL];

                [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerPortrait belowSubview:actionTabBar];


            }
        }
        else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            if ([jumpBarContainerPortrait superview])
            {
            // Device is changing from portrait to landscape change views to fit
            // load landscape view
            jumpBarContainerLandscape = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, (207 - jumpBarHeightLandscape), 480.0,  (jumpBarHeightLandscape + 49.0))];
            jumpBarContainerLandscape.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
            jumpBarContainerLandscape.alpha = 1.0;

            // add jumpbar container to view

                [UIView transitionFromView:jumpBarContainerPortrait
                                    toView:jumpBarContainerLandscape
                                  duration:animationSpeed
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                completion:NULL];

                [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarContainerLandscape belowSubview:actionTabBar];



            }

        }
    }
}
```

in this example, I have two views landscape and portrait, obviously as the names go each are for their respective orientations.. the logic above goes along the lines of this

```
if tabbarselected 

if !view visible
if device orientation portrait 
animate in portrait view.
if device orientation landscape
animate in landscape view

if view visible
if device orientation portrait
animate out portrait view
clear tabbar
if device orientation landscape
animate out landscape view
clear tabbar

if !tabbarselected //meaning listener has identified orientation of device has changed 

if device orientation portrait
unload portrait 
load landscape

if device orientation landscape
unload landscape
load portrait
```

I would like to know if there is an easier way than going through all of this hassle! I am still fairly inexperienced so this was my best attempt.. I am hoping someone out there knows of an easier approach than having to do all of this leg work to get views being added to other views as subviews adjusting for orientation properly

any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm desperate lol :)

Comment: You should be using a **`switch`** statement here.

Comment: hrmm.. I find switch statements good for situations where you have several options on the same variable or what have you.. however when I have a mixture of variables I need to check I find it hard to tell where a switch would be good.. do you think I could just replace all of the if statements with switch?

Comment: Why not set the autoSizing mask when you first create your frame. That way it resizes automatically when you change orientation?

Comment: im going to go read apple docs.. I have not seen how to do this. I thought auto resize was only avalible in Interface Builder.

Comment: Check out autoresizingMask property of UIView. Works like a champ and greatly simplifies this sort of stuff. `yourSubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Comment: okay cool thanks! going to try it out now :P I just tried **self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;** but it didnt work.. I think because I have defined the CGMakeRect values so its overriding the autoresize.. going to have a play round now! :) thanks for the input

Comment: Also, minor thing, but rather than hard coding numbers in your CGRectMake, I always use the superview's dimensions, e.g., `self.view.frame.size.width` and `self.view.frame.size.height`. Handles different screen dimensions (which might be an iPhone 5 issue), different orientations, presence or absence of container controllers like navigationController or tabController, etc.

Comment: No, you have to say what struts and springs you want. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask

Comment: okay perfect thanks very much.. I think I have been getting confused with the fact I have a a few other things on the screen at the same time so was hard coding the sizes thanks very much for the heads up! going to go give it a crack now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`autoresizingMask` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask). Gives you all the same springs and struts control that you have in Interface Builder. E.g.:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(margin, margin, self.view.frame.size.width - margin * 2, self.view.frame.size.height - margin * 2);
UIView *mySubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view mySubview];
mySubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Also, if you decide that autoresizingMask is not enough (for example, when you're moving objects with respect to each other to really fine tune the portrait versus landscape orientation), I'd suggest you do this layout process in [`viewWillLayoutSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) for iOS5, (or [`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) in iOS4 or earlier). This way you don't need to animate the change yourself and the animation will be done in conjunction with the rest of the screen rotation animation.

Comment: today **mySubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;** saved my life ;) cheers again dude.. code is looks so much better